# Trouble with total time

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

Need help with this.
I have seen other answers but didn't understand them that well. How can I print the time difference between the start and stop time in hour and minutes?

```
NSDateFormatter *Formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[Formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
if (count == 0) {
    _startTime.text = [Formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [sender setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}else {
    _stopTime.text = [Formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    _startStopLabel.hidden = YES;
    //write to UILabel "totalTime" the difference between the stop and start times in hours, minutes.
}
```

If anything is needed please just ask :) (first post)
thanks all :)

Comment: I didn't understood what you wan't, what's not working.

Comment: sorry, its in the code next to the //, "    //write to UILabel "totalTime" the difference between the stop and start times in hours, minutes."

Comment: I edited to add something to that effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subtract the dates and then convert the resulting time interval:

```
NSDateFormatter *Formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[Formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate date1 = nil;
if (count == 0) {
    date1 = [NSDate date];
    _startTime.text = [Formatter stringFromDate:date1];
    [sender setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}else {
    NSDate date2 = [NSDate date];
    _stopTime.text = [Formatter stringFromDate:date2];
    _startStopLabel.hidden = YES;

    long diff = (long)[date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
    diff /= 60; //Convert to minutes
    //write to UILabel "totalTime" the difference between the stop and start times in hours, minutes.
    _totalTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours, %d minutes", diff/60, diff%60];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, i keep getting the same answer of "-596523 hours, -14 minutes". Any ideas?